# Use lisp to output something while in cond

Tags: lisp, scheme

```
(define length1
 (lambda (lat)
  (cond 
   ((null? lat) 0)
   (else (+ 1 (length1 (cdr lat)))))))
```

for example: display the number (or anything else) when call length1 in `cond`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for common lisp you can use `(progn (...) (...) ...)` to group together multiple expressions into one.

the equivalent in scheme is `(begin (...) (...) ...)`.

so:

```
(define length1
 (lambda (lat)
  (cond 
   ((null? lat) 0)
   (else (begin (display "hello world") (+ 1 (length1 (cdr lat))))))))
```

or maybe you want:

```
(define length1
 (lambda (lat)
  (cond 
   ((null? lat) 0)
   (else (let ((or-anything-else (+ 1 (length1 (cdr lat)))))
            (display or-anything-else)
            or-anything-else)))
```

and that's about exhausted my patience.

Comment: How to display current count number `0 1 2 3 4 ...` ?

Comment: (+ 1 (length1 (cdr lat))) or (length1 (cdr lat)) ? in every recursive

Comment: but that will call itself, won't it?

Comment: yes, want to display the number but don't call lenght1 two times